# Flutter build apk

Tags: flutter

Getting error trying to flutter build apk

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\BringApp-Delivery-service-app-main\users_food_app> flutter build apk

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 33 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" finished.
lib/widgets/simple_app_bar.dart:5:49: Error: The class 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.
class SimpleAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
^
lib/widgets/app_bar.dart:7:44: Error: The class 'PreferredSizeWidget' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.
class MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-2.3.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutt
er/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
import 'asset_manifest.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' has fewer named arguments than those
of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/interface/file.dart:15:16: Error: The method 'File.create' doesn't have the named parameter 'exc
lusive' of overridden method 'File.create'.
Future create({bool recursive = false});
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:232:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('create').
Future create({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' has fewer na
med arguments than those of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file-6.1.2/lib/src/forwarding/forwarding_file.dart:22:8: Error: The method 'ForwardingFile.createSync' doesn't have
the named parameter 'exclusive' of overridden method 'File.createSync'.
void createSync({bool recursive = false}) =>
^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/io/file.dart:248:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('createSync').
void createSync({bool recursive = false, bool exclusive = false});
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-2.3.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:32:31: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flut
ter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
AssetManifest assetManifest = AssetManifest();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-6.1.10/lib/src/action_code_info.dart:65:15: Error: The method 'FallThroughError' i
sn't defined for the class 'ActionCodeInfo'.

- 'ActionCodeInfo' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/action_code_info.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_pl
  atform_interface-6.1.10/lib/src/action_code_info.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FallThroughError'.
  throw FallThroughError();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:661:31: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:662:38: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:664:29: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.3.3/lib/src/structs.g.dart:665:36: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
  ^^^^^^^^^

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 51s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          294.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: What's here: lib/widgets/app_bar.dart?